# Tag based biling or backup in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, labeler

I want to create enforce policy in google(GCP) the same as in azure so whenever any user creates the new VM or any resource it will force him to add the tags defined by the admin(me) compulsory. Please provide the solution or any document if have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not aware of a Google Cloud feature that enforces this. You could write a Cloud Function that monitors your projects and takes action such as sending an email but this would be developed by your team and is not a Google Cloud feature.

Comment: Thanks, John for this information...could you please tell me how do I create/write the enforce policy using the function to send email... I am a beginner in GCP and have no idea how to create the function if you don't mind could you help me.

Comment: There are numberous getting started guides and documents on Cloud Functions.